# User can't delete file owned by user with w permission

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync, rm

I've a backup system based on rsync.

Get a problem when try delete one file

```
srv106@storage10:~$ rm -vf /srv/storage/homes/srv106/daily/files/daily.32/root/.my.cnf
rm: cannot remove `/srv/storage/homes/srv106/daily/files/daily.32/root/.my.cnf': Permission denied
```

But permission are correct

```
205783621 4 -rw------- 36 srv106 srv106 39 Mar 20  2014 /srv/storage/homes/srv106/daily/files/daily.32/root/.my.cnf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are removing the file from the directory, it doesn't matter what kind of permissions you have on the file, what matters is that you have write and execute permissions on the directory.

If you do have them, I'd check mounts and check whether the filesystem that the file is on is mounted read-only..

Comment: Another possibility are extended permissions. The user might list them using the `lsattr` command, if the `i` flag is listed, it means the file is immutable and therefore cannot be deleted even by the root user. To disable that flag, the following command would need to be run: `chattr -i filename`

Comment: Aprecite your help, I run ls for every dir, and get error. Because unkwon rason, rsync put wrong permison on /srv/storage/homes/srv106/daily/files/daily.32/root/ 550 instead original 755... thanks... I'm going to lacet problem with rsync.